# Avoiding empty Local Storage entry in Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to make a cookie-less website to avoid the EU Cookie banner, but Chrome always shows at least one cookie entry, even though it's empty.

[image]

I guess I dont have to worry about it, still is there a way to avoid this entry with html or javascript code?

Comment: ianal, but afaik you don't need any EU cookie banner, there is no law about this. You need to show the people if/how you store their data. independent of cookie or localstorage.